# issues related to passing an array from controller to javascript in view in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, string, jquery-ui

I have created an array of strings in the new action of my controller. Now I want to pass this array to the jquery function used in my view file. I have tried to_json and html_safe options but I did not get the result yet.

Please help me to find a way out.

My code snippet of controller where the array is initiated and generated is:
(My array name is firstname_array)

```
def string_include(substring,data_ref)
loo=0
firstname_array=Array.new

data_ref.each do |d_ref|  
    puts "in the loop of string_include method"
    my_string=d_ref.compact_string

    if my_string.include? substring
        puts "String "+ my_string+" includes "+substring
        loo=loo+1
        puts loo
        puts d_ref.firstname
        firstname_array && firstname_array.push(d_ref.firstname)
    end

end
puts "This is the array"
puts firstname_array
return 100
end
```

The javascript code in my view is:
(I want to copy the same array from controller into the array named availableTags used in my jquery function.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
var availableTags=new Array
availableTags=<%= firstname_array.to_json.html_safe %> ;

document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML = availableTags;

$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use view helper j

```
<%= j(firstname_array) %>
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html

You can also use this as well inside view

```
var array = [<%= raw firstname_array.to_json %>];
```

Hope it helps

EDIT:

I think this should work (no need for new Array since it is overwritten in second line)

```
var availableTags= [<%= raw firstname_array.to_json %>];
```

Comment: its a string array,,,so it just to_json enough? just asking!!

Comment: Probably not. Depends what is inside. But if you look at documentation you will see that there is JS_ESCAPE_MAP - so you have to encode some chars properly in order to pickup from javascript. If you want to pass javascript array then trick with raw will work. To make sure that javascript does not break I think the safest would be using j helper/. It is used in UJS response to that will work.

Comment: What did you tried exactly. See my edit please and just use this line instead var availableTags= [<%= raw firstname_array.to_json %>];

Comment: no actually I have tried this for availableTag name ,,,but its still not working.....the error is undefined local variable or method `firstname_array' for #<#<Class:0x0000000695b838>:0x000000065f2570>

Comment: You need to pass in an instance variable to the view or define in the view helper. Your view does not see the firstname_array. So inside controller action define @ firstname_array and populate it...and then use my trick with raw but this time use var availableTags= [<%= raw @firstname_array.to_json %>];

Comment: yes it is working ...now can you guide me on another issue?  Like I am using jquery autocomple mechanism. It needs an array on which this javascript will run and show the result on typing.Thats why I need the availableTags array. But problem is that javascript is loading only the time of page loading and it is capturing the initial array but I need the javascript to be called dynamically during the type of each keyword typing...so how can I resolve this?

Comment: I would recommend closing this question and posting another one related to autocomplete and remote option.